# PhpStorm inferring `mixed` type on my typed properties

Tags: php, types, phpstorm

I've been working recently with classes that initialize themselves from an array of data, and have typed properties which are set with values retrieved from the array.

The properties are typed, which means PHP will throw a TypeError if anything besides the specified type is passed in.

However, PhpStorm appears to be propogating the `mixed` type from the array access to the class property.

I'm struggling to explain it in words, so here's an example script:

```php
<?php

class TestClass
{
    public readonly string $myString;
    public readonly int $myInt;
    public readonly array $myArray;

    public function __construct(array $src)
    {
        $this->myString = $src['stringVal'];
        $this->myInt = $src['intVal'];
        $this->myArray = $src['array'];
    }
}

$arr = [
    'stringVal' => 123,
    'intVal' => "I am a string",
    'array' => null,
];

$x = new TestClass($arr); // throws TypeError from within the constructor

$y = new TestClass($x->myInt); // PhpStorm doesn't see anything wrong with this???
```

You can see that there are types on all 3 of the properties.  You can look at the script and see that it will fail.  The script as written throws a TypeError exactly as you'd expect when it tries to set `$this->myString`.

However, if I hover over any of the class properties, PhpStorm is adding the `mixed` type to the property:

[image: Screenshot showing the PhpStorm propup with mixed|string as the type on the property $myString]

Since PhpStorm is treating all of the properties as "x or mixed", it doesn't see anything wrong with the obviously incorrect last line of the script, where we're trying to pass an int to the constructor, which requires an array:

[image: Screenshot showing that PhpStorm doesn't show any error on the final line of the script]

How can I get PhpStorm to stop inferring `mixed` on these properties?

Update: it's not only `mixed` coming from an array, it seems that PhpStorm is just assuming that whatever happens in the constructor is valid, regardless of the types on the properties(?)

Another example:

```php
class TestClass2
{
    public readonly int $myInt;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->myInt = "hello world";
    }
}
```

The constructor throws a TypeError, again just as you'd expect.  But PhpStorm seems content to assume that the property will accept a string:

[image: Screenshot showing PhpStorm's popup with the type int|string on $myInt]

Comment: You may be able to help PHPStorm type hinting with this: `$this->myInt = (int)$src['intVal'];` enforced type casting. Personally I think enforced casting is very good for ensuring that `0` is recognised as `0` even if it's erroneously saved as `'0'` , etc.

Comment: Doesn't explain PhpStorm's behavior, which you should tell JetBrains about in a bug report, but you can do something very similar and without the mapping: `https://3v4l.org/Jj47T#v8.1.17 Frankly, using an array to initialize a class like the above code obscures important details and shouldn't be the bother of the class to take that on.

Comment: You can submit a PHPStorm [bug report **here**](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI)

Comment: @Martin I've done that casting trick in some places, but I don't think I'm going to change the habits of everyone else to work around an (apparent) bug/config issue in my IDE :)

Comment: @JaredFarrish I didn't know about that initialization syntax, that looks super useful!

Comment: I'm a little on the fence about things being too cute. For instance, in that example, the properties (which are public) are mapped directly, without mediation. When would an array come into it? Perhaps stored in context of something else. You can end up having a difficult time changing those properties if what's initializing the object is stored in state and not easily or practically seen/modified (especially through refactor tooling). If you're going to use arrays this way, I would suggest creating static `with<>()` methods that map that array for you, and name them appropriately.

Comment: Example using `with` initializer: https://3v4l.org/mUqSd#v8.1.17

Comment: @JaredFarrish This is admittedly a contrived example to illustrate the IDE issue I'm trying to resolve - I wouldn't advocate to write a class like this normally :) The real-world scenarios I'm working with have a bit more complexity to them, but boil down to "the IDE isn't doing the right thing when I assign something incorrect/suspicious in the constructor".

Comment: Right, and that should be reported to JetBrains.

Comment: Gotcha.  I was hoping that there would be a setting or something that I was missing, but I'll file a bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I filed a [bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-72190/PhpStorm-fails-to-enforce-type-of-typed-property-when-a-different-incorrect-type-is-assigned-in-the-constructor) to JetBrains, and they gave me the following workaround:

> As a workaround, you can either mark the file with `declare(strict_types=1);` or enable the *PHP | Type compatibility | Strict type checking rules violation: Enable for all files*.

In my case, the code inspection setting was most appropriate and solved the issue for me.